# What is the point of setArgument in DialogFragment's?

Tags: android, bundle

I have this piece of code:

```
public static DateDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, DateDialogFragmentListener listener) {
    DateDialogFragment dialog = new DateDialogFragment();
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;
    /*I dont really see the purpose of the below*/
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", "Set Date");
    dialog.setArguments(args);

    return dialog;
}
```

Pretty self explanatory, but what I don't understand is what the point of giving it a Bundle. I never really make use of it I guess. The Android Doc's explanation of this (for Fragments) is here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)
What exactly does a construction argument mean? Since its never used, I fail to see the use of it. Any explanation much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply a generic mechanism for you to attach data values that you might want to use to configure the `Fragment` or otherwise read during operation, similar to how you might pass extras in a `Bundle` to a new `Activity` via it's `Intent`.

I do agree, however, that since a `Fragment` can be instantiated using its constructor, where an `Activity` cannot, the usefulness of the API may seem compromised because you can just as easily configure a `Fragment` using setter methods and member variables inside of `newInstance()` before returning the instance.  For example, your code could implement a method on the `Fragment` called `setTitle()` that you could call, and you wouldn't need to pass that as an argument.  However, arguments do provide a nice way of storing this information as key/value data if that model fits your application.

One key distinction about the arguments of a `Fragment` is that they are retained as part of the saved instance state.  So if your UI rotates or some other change requires the `Fragment` to be recreated, the arguments `Bundle` attached will be retained and handed back to the new instance.

HTH

Comment: Hmm, so if I wanted to get the `"title"` back from the fragment, I could through the saved instance?

Comment: Sure, or you could just implement a `getTitle()` method as well for the `Activity` or other container to call.  The key is arguments will be persisted if your `Fragment` get recreated by the system, usually due to a configuration change.

Comment: Why thank you very much. One more question if you don't mind. I need to be able to save some form of state in that same DialogFragment, but after its been attached to the parent activity, meaning `setArgument()` can't work. How can I save something in the fragment to retrieve if its opened again?

Comment: Why won'y `setArguments()` work?  That and it's corresponding get method can be called at any time, both internally and externally to the fragment.

Comment: Look at the Android Docs. It specifically says so. At least in terms of officially creating the Bundle. But in either case, I don't really ever use it. So I haven't tested it out.

Comment: Ah, fair enough :o.  If you need to save the state surrounding configuration changes, there `onSaveInstanceState()`.  Otherwise, you might consider setting the fragment itself to be retained with `setRetainInstance()` so any data you see in members isn't lost.

Comment: If you want to save additional information, can you not call getArugments() and the add information to that Bundle?  The Bundle you get is still attached to the Fragment, isn't it?

Comment: Assuming you had initially passed an arguments `Bundle` (even if it was empty), sure.  Stuff the data in whichever `Bundle` you prefer, but `onSaveInstanceState()` would still be the time and place in which to do so.